# Method 'onBackPressed()' recurses infinitely, and can only end by throwing an exception

Tags: android

Method 'onBackPressed()' recurses infinitely, and can only end by throwing an exception any way to stop it?

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: instead of finish(); try "super.onBackPressed()"

Comment: nothing seems wrong except you are not showing the dialog but that won't throw exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            showAlertDialog("Tap again to exit!", "Your_app_name");
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }
```

I represent showAlertDialog(),which is a method for alert dialog. U can use normal dialog.

By this code, When the stack becomes 0, it pop up for alert for getting exit from app. Otherwise it pop up the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You are building your dialog but you do not create and show it. Just add the following line of code and you're good to go.

```
builder.create().show();
```